# .htaccess issue to force SSL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I activated SSL on one of my sites (based on wordpress) and want to modify `.htaccess` to modify content's links to https.
I mean, into `https://www.example.com/products.html` page is a `http://example.com/blah-blah.jpg`
i want to change it to `https://www.example.com/blah-blah.jpg` via `.htaccess`
and i don't have any idea! :|
I installed and activated `HTTPS for WordPress` plugin but some links not change to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr. Schulman's solution forgets the slash after the domain name, so the user is redirected to **https://www.example.comcategory/cat1/cat2/** which is not quite right.  I added a slash to his .htaccess entry, and it worked just fine.  Consider:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*)  https://example.com/$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*)  https://www.example.com$1 [R]
```

Of course this will require that you have [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled.

Comment: How redirect an address like this `http://www.example.com/category/cat1/cat2/`
to `httpS://www.example.com/category/cat1/cat2/`

Comment: That is exactly what the above code does.  Per the documentation for [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), the `(.*)` in the rule only matches the part of the request after the scheme and hostname, so that's what gets substituted for $1 in the target.

Comment: i just want exactly 'category' url redirect to 'https' version, is there any tutorial to learn this wildcard patterns? i searched but not found anything good! :|

Comment: As the documentation for RewriteRule says, the pattern `(.*)` is a regular expression.  If you search for 'regular expression tutorial' you can easily find some.